# Jquery conflict in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Hi I am learning Javascript and am stuck resolving a JS related issue on my project http://www.merekhayaal.com/ I have installed Masonry layout which is conflicting with the rest of JS. I have read this usually has to do with fixing  jQuery. I am only asking for pointers here. I need the following code to make the Masonry layout work:

```
<script src="babezlondon/modernizr-latest.js">

</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/shopshark/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="babezlondon/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="babezlondon/script.js"></script>
```

But when I put this in, the rest of JS on the page breaks. If the solution is to implement no-conflict in jQuery, what steps can I take to ensure I do it correctly in my case as there are multiple js files to deal with?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I got two 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' errors for prototype.js and one for jquery.menu.js. I have put the code back in and you can see the result if you have time. I am sure the fix is something really simple but as I am new to this am a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using jQuery noConflict?  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: I copied something off the web without really understanding it but i ll try modifying it as you ve described and report the results

Answer (score 0):

Just use `jQuery` in `noConflict()` mode.

Stick this at the bottom of the jQuery script;

```
var $jq=jQuery.noConflict();
```

so now you would have to use `$jq` instead of `$jQuery` or `$`

This way, each script you have for different sliders etc you can change the var `$jq` to suit.

Hope this helps.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: There are so many js files that I am confused which to change, there is modernzr, theme files, masonry, extensions' js and on top of that two different versions of jquery are being used

Comment: I would keep the latest jQuery version loaded and remove the rest and test. If any of your JS files are using $ use the above method to change it to use another. Prototype which magento is based on can cause issues when jQuery is using the $ variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what worked is when i removed a line of code

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

from the script. It was apparently causing the conflict